# Using System Hosts file for Android Emulators

Tags: android, emulation, hosts

I having problem in using my system hosts file details in Android Emulators. 
I have my website (www.example.com) deployed in Webserver. 
I am trying to access those website in Emulator from my desktop.
My desktop has a hosts file with the entry of

10.xx.xx.xx      www.example.com

I am trying to access the www.example.com from the android emulator - browser and it is not working.

I took a reference from the below website, but most of the website says how to use the hosts file if the website is deployed in the same server.

http://sadhanasiblog.blogspot.in/2012/07/local-environment-setup-for-android.html

Please let me know if anyone has answers. Thanks in Advance.

-Senthil

Comment: Go through this link [http://borkweb.com/story/setting-etchosts-on-an-android-emulator-using-a-mac](http://borkweb.com/story/setting-etchosts-on-an-android-emulator-using-a-mac) It is worked for me

Answer (score 15):

With latest Android studio and tools. You can now use follow this instructions. You only need to run this once per emulator.

1. Start the emulator with following command. This command is located under your [sdk folder]/tools directory

   ```
   emulator @[emulator name] -writable-system
   ```
2. Open another command prompt and then switch your directory to [sdk folder]/platform-tools and run following commands

   ```
   adb root
   adb remount
   adb shell
   echo '10.0.2.2 [localserver dns name]'>>/etc/hosts        -- example echo '10.0.2.2 xxxx.com'>>/etc/hosts
   ```

Comment: the `-writable-system` is the most important bit you won't find mentioned anywhere else

Comment: I think one more step was remaining which rebooting the device to apply these changes, by executing this command: adb reboot

Comment: This only work with emulators *without the play store*. Otherwise adb root fails.

Answer (score 10):

One important thing to check is, if you create your HOSTS file on Windows or MacOS machine, that the **HOSTS file contains linux line endings** ('\n', LF, #10, #0x0A). Android ignores the HOSTS file if it contains Windows' 2-char line endings ('\r\n', CRLF, #13#10, #0x0D0A) or MacOS-style line endings ('\r', CR, #13, #0x0D).

**Except for letters/numbers/dots (used for IP and host names) the file should contain only characters 0x20 (space), 0x09 (tab) and 0x0A (new line).**

Comment: THANK YOU! I spent a day on trying to figure this out, until I finally found this awesome post!

Answer (score 3):

To acces to your localhost the IP is

> 10.0.2.2   Special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine)

From Android docs:

> At startup, the emulator reads the list of DNS servers that your system is currently using. It then stores the IP addresses of up to four servers on this list and sets up aliases to them on the emulated addresses 10.0.2.3, 10.0.2.4, 10.0.2.5 and 10.0.2.6 as needed.
>
> On Linux and OS X, the emulator obtains the DNS server addresses by parsing the file /etc/resolv.conf. On Windows, the emulator obtains the addresses by calling the GetNetworkParams() API. Note that this usually means that the emulator ignores the content of your "hosts" file (/etc/hosts on Linux/OS X, %WINDOWS%/system32/HOSTS on Windows).
>
> When starting the emulator at the command line, you can also use the -dns-server  option to manually specify the addresses of DNS servers to use, where  is a comma-separated list of server names or IP addresses. You might find this option useful if you encounter DNS resolution problems in the emulated network (for example, an "Unknown Host error" message that appears when using the web browser).

At your console use:

`emulator -avd <you_avd_name> -dns-server <serverList>`

I used when I had to connect to a VirtualBox with a linux distro on the same PC and it worked from the emulator webview `http://10.0.2.3/servlet-name`

[Reference: Emulator Networking](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking)